# Conversion from 3 dimension geometry to 2 dimension using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, dimensions

I have a Point table in which the geometry column contains both 3 dimension and 2 dimension values.  I want to convert this 3 dimensional geometry to 2 dimension.

Is there any function in PostGIS?

Answer (score 18):

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Force_2D.html

SELECT ST_Force_2D(the_geom) FROM...

Update your existing table

```
 
ALTER TABLE your_geo_table ADD geom2d geometry;
UPDATE your_geo_table SET geom2d = ST_Force_2D(the_geom);
```

See also http://postgis.net/docs/

Comment: Use `ST_Force2D` instead of `ST_Force_2d`. `ST_Force_2d` signature was deprecated in 2.1.0.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to add a new column you can also do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE your_geo_table  
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(YOUR_GEOM_TYPE, YOUR_EPSG) 
    USING ST_Force_2D(geom);
```

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE your_geo_table  
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 4326) 
    USING ST_Force_2D(geom);
```

Comment: As of early 2023 the function is now called `ST_Force2D`, not `ST_Force_2D`.