# Updating PostGIS layer from another vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0

I have a vector layer that contains way points that I load using "load vector layer" from a gpx file.   I am attempting to add these new points to an existing postgis layer by simply copying and pasting between the layers.

When I first tried this I got an error "Column has Z dimension but geometry does not".  Sure enough the PostGIS table was 2D so I converted the geometry to pointz and retried but I still get the same error?

database manager now shows the the_geom of the postgis table as

```
6  the_geom geometry (PointZ,2193)
```

How can I inspect the geometry of a layer from within QGIS? Any other suggestions on how to figure out what is really wrong.

Comment: Did you remove and reload the PostGIS layer in QGIS after you converted the geometry in the database?

Comment: good point, but yes - I actually restarted qgis.

Comment: Restarting QGIS won't update the properties QGIS is associating with the layer if the table properties in the database were changed. It's more obvious when you add or a remove a column to the table - if you restart QGIS it will still only look for the columns that the layer had when it was initially added. Only adding the layer from the database again will update it.

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, the solution is as follows: 1) save your layer from the paths to the PostGIS table, 2) Convert the path table data to 2D https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/conversion-from-3-dimension -geometry-to-2-dimension, make sure that the SRID is the same in them and then there will be no problems with geodata