# Need to convert coord_dimension from 4 to 2. File contains 2D polygons

Tags: postgis, coordinates, dimensions

I am working with PostGIS Bundle 2.5 in PostgreSQL 11. I loaded a MultiPolygon file from a geodatbase and I need to append the geometry table to an existing geometry table. However, the coordinate dimensions of the new table is set to 4 (even though it only contains 2D polygons) and the coordinate dimensions of the original table is 2, so I get "ERROR: Geometry has Z dimension but column does not".

How can I reset the coordinate dimensions of the geometry table from 4 to 2?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/conversion-from-3-dimension-geometry-to-2-dimension but syntax is slightly different for v. 11: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force2D.html